# monkey patching Object produces strange results

Tags: ruby, windows, io, monkeypatching

I was hacking a `to_hash` to Object (I'm not saying this is a good idea, just an experiment). When I came across an odd issue, where `IO` stopped working.

```
#lib/object.rb
class Object
  def to_hash
    self.instance_variables.inject({}) { |hash,var| hash[var.to_s.delete("@")] = self.instance_variable_get(var); hash } 
  end
end

#run_test1.rb
require_relative 'lib/Object'
require 'FileUtils'

puts 'run test'


#run_test2.rb
require_relative 'lib/Object'

File.open('test.txt', 'w') {|f| f.write('this is a test')}
```

in run_test1 I get an

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `set_encoding': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2) (ArgumentError)
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from .../run_test1.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

in run_test2 I get

```
run_test2.rb:3:in `initialize': No such file or directory - test.txt (Errno::ENOENT
        from run_test2.rb:3:in `open'
        from run_test2.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

(if the file exists it says the file is not open for writing)

While I'm not surprised it happened - just curious, What is going on here? Theoretically it should be fine, however what is the underlying cause.

The relevant info:

- ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09) [i386-mingw32]
- XP SP3 32-bit
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.12

Comment: Who woulda thought changing a low-level object could have unintended consequences, crazy! To discover *why* this breaks things in the way it does (it's much more exciting under `pry`) you might have to trace some C even, to determine why `to_hash` specifically breaks things--maybe something else tries to define it, but doesn't since it's already there. Who knows. `to_hashish` works fine, so it's clearly symbol-related.

Comment: Why the close-/down-vote? It's valid to want to know *why* this breaks something (particularly in the way it does), even if being surprised is a little funny.

Comment: thanks I will look into pry as I continue on my path to break other things...looks fun

Comment: With ruby 1.9.3p0, `run_test1` just works. `run_test2` doesnt, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `to_hash` method is used to identify objects that coerce to Hash. In that sense, it behaves like `to_ary` or `to_str`. The method you implemented is more like `to_a` or `to_s`.

Lots of Ruby code, including Ruby core code, checks for `to_hash` to figure out whether an argument is an options hash (`arg.respond_to? :to_hash`) and from there on follow a different execution path. This gets even more messed up by some code checking if the object is a real hash or not (`Hash === arg`).

You might want to name your method `to_h` or something similar.